# Sum based on date column

Tags: sql, sum, firebird, interbase

I have a table but I will have to sum the total of purchases based on the Docdate column. I am using Firebird Interbase. I have tried the following, however I do not seem to see what I am doing wrong. Any advise it will be greatly appreaciated.

My query only returns my own results without summing the purchases column:

```
DOCTYPE DESCRIPTION STUDENTID   DOCDATE VOUCHERDATE DOCNUMB PURCHASES   NAME    TOTAL
1   800130-EE20180810   800130  8/04/2018   8/04/2018   800130-EE20180810   2.99        
1   800130-EE20180810   800130  8/04/2018   8/04/2018   800130-EE20180810   5.39        
1   800130-EE20180810   800130  8/04/2018   8/04/2018   800130-EE20180810   1.03        
1   800130-EE20150810   800130  7/24/2015   7/24/2015   800130-EE20150810   8.99        
1   800130-EE20150810   800130  7/24/2015   7/24/2015   800130-EE20150810   15.32       
1   800130-EE20150810   800130  7/24/2015   7/24/2015   800130-EE20150810   2.93
```

Expected results:

```
DOCTYPE DESCRIPTION STUDENTID   DOCDATE VOUCHERDATE DOCNUMB PURCHASES   NAME    TOTAL
1   800130-EE20180810   800130  8/04/2018   8/04/2018   800130-EE20180810   9.41
1   800130-EE20150810   800130  7/24/2015   7/24/2015   800130-EE20150810   27.24
```

My query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  '1' AS DOCTYPE
 ,DESCRIPTION
    ,STUDENTID
    ,DOCDATE
    ,VOUCHERDATE
    ,DOCNUMB
    ,PURCHASES
    ,NAME
    ,TOTAL
 ,SUM(cast(PURCHASES as decimal(18,5)) )AS PURCHASES
 ,'' AS CCNAME
 ,'' AS CCTOTAL
 FROM   TableA


WHERE 

GROUP BY DESCRIPTION,STUDENTID,DOCDATE,VOUCHERDATE,DOCNUMB,PURCHASES
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "Firebird Interbase". You're using either Firebird or Interbase - which one?

Comment: Firebird and InterBase are two distinct database systems. They may have the same origin, but they have diverged over the past 18 years. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't include PURCHASES in the `GROUP BY` if you want to `SUM` up the PURCHASES.

And remove it also from the SELECT while at it.
Then only use PURCHASES in an aggregate function like `SUM`,`MAX`,`AVG`, ...

Also, you can remove that `DISTINCT`.
Because the `GROUP BY` should already be sufficient to return unique records.

So try this:

```
SELECT 
 '1' AS DOCTYPE,
 DESCRIPTION, STUDENTID, DOCDATE, VOUCHERDATE, DOCNUMB,
 MAX(NAME) AS NAME,
 SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTAL,
 CAST(SUM(PURCHASES) AS DECIMAL(18,5)) AS PURCHASES,
 '' AS CCNAME,
 '' AS CCTOTAL
FROM TableA AS a
WHERE STUDENTID = 800130
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION, STUDENTID, DOCDATE, VOUCHERDATE, DOCNUMB
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the columns are unique to each purchase and would vary by purchase row, remove them from the query.

Using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` will give you more control over the results.

```
SELECT
    '1' AS DOCTYPE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    STUDENTID,
    DOCDATE,
    VOUCHERDATE,
    DOCNUMB,
    PURCHASES,
    NAME,
    TOTAL,
    SUM(cast(PURCHASES as decimal(18,5)) )AS PURCHASES,
    '' AS CCNAME,
    '' AS CCTOTAL
 FROM   TableA
 GROUP BY DESCRIPTION,
    STUDENTID,
    DOCDATE,
    VOUCHERDATE,
    DOCNUMB,
    NAME,
    TOTAL
```